# Easiest way to access Phalcon config values in views?

Tags: php, phalcon, volt

I have a section in ini files with some globally used social links, for ex:

```
[social]
fb = URL
twitter = URL
linkedin = URL
```

What's the easiest way to access these, or is there a better way to organize these global variables?

Comment: $config = new \Phalcon\Config\Adapter\Ini("path/config.ini"); from http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/config.html

Comment: how can I access that in a view file though? edit: volt

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13186966/cross-controller-variables-in-phalcon

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If you read your config file upon initialization/bootstraping your application AND store it in the DI container, then it will be accessible through that in every part of your app.

Example - bootstrap

```
$di         = new \Phalcon\DI\FactoryDefault();
$configFile = ROOT_PATH . '/app/var/config/config.ini';

// Create the new object
$config = new \Phalcon\Config\Adapter\Ini($configFile);

// Store it in the Di container
$di->set('config', $config);
```

Now you can access this in your controller as such:

```
echo $this->config->social->twitter;
```

Views via Volt:

```
{{ config.social.twitter }}
```

You can always set that particular part of your config in your views through a base controller.

```
class ControllerBase() 
{
    public function initialize()
    {
        parent::initialize();

        $this->view->setVar('social', $this->config->social);
    }
}
```

and then access that variable through your view:

```
{{ social.twitter }}
```