# How to add a global accessible variable for Phalcon Micro framework?

Tags: php, variables, global, phalcon

I'm new to PHP Phalcon and I'm creating a simple REST API backend, I now encounter a problem.

```
//define $app in index.php
$app = new Micro($di) ;
```

In one controller I'm trying to define (add) a global accessible variable between controllers at least.

```
//However, the followings are all not working.
$this->currentWeixinAccessToken = $access_token ;
$this->getDI()->setShared('currentWeixinAccessToken', $access_token);
$this->$currentWeixinAccessToken = $access_token;
$this->di->setShared('currentWeixinAccessToken', $access_token) ;
```

They can be defined without error, but when I'm using them in another controller,

```
$access_token = $this->currentWeixinAccessToken;
```

The error is,

```
[Sat Jul 30 22:10:20 2016] PHP Notice:  Access to undefined property currentWeixinAccessToken in /home/tom/src/phalcontest/app/controllers/PostsController.php on line 48
```

And I found some answers here, but they don't work for me.
[Cross controller variables in Phalcon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13186966/cross-controller-variables-in-phalcon)

Comment: If controller B extends controller A this should work. But in the way you described it is not possible. I guess you are looking for something like Sessions behavior, but not exactly ;)

If that variable is added to the $di you will be able to access it.

Comment: Yes it will like session behavior, but this variable will be all the same through all sessions/

Comment: Is the other controller (postcontroller) accessing it from the same request? Or is it on another page

Answer (score 1):

When you add something to dependency injector you need to call it through di. That's why you should try using `$access_token = $this->di->currentWeixinAccessToken` instead in your second controller. Di is by default accessible from controller in full Phalcon, I'm not sure what about micro version. If it doesn't work you can try using `\Phalcon\Di::getDefault()->currentWeixinAccessToken` or `\Phalcon\Di::getDefault()->get('currentWeixinAccessToken')`

Comment: @tomriddle_1234 please mark the post as answer if it worked out

Comment: unfortunately, I tried this and it is not working...Service 'currentWeixinAccessToken' wasn't found in the dependency injection container,  Undefined property: Phalcon\Di\FactoryDefault::$currentWeixinAccessToken

Comment: You're using it wrong. Use one of exact lines I wrote in the answer for instance `\Phalcon\Di::getDefault()->currentWeixinAccessToken` or `\Phalcon\Di::getDefault()->get('currentWeixinAccessToken')`